# Horizontal scroll with buttons in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have implemented following horizontal scroll with buttons, but it seems like it starts scrolling only after 5 seconds. It got stuck. UI is getting blocked, I guess.

I have following code to create that in my `ViewDidLoad()`

```
 UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height-100, self.view.frame.size.width, 100)];

    int x = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,10,80,80)];
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTag:i];
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickofFilter:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [scrollView addSubview:button];

        x += button.frame.size.width+10;
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

[image: Image showing a row of green buttons on a red background.]

Is there any way to make it smooth?

Comment: Your adding scroll view after for loop , That's why it's delay because for loop completed then it is load and set button = nil if arc otherwise "[button release]" after adding button

Comment: Better to use collection view apple is introduce UICollectionView Try it

Comment: scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x, scrollView.frame.size.height); This line of code is possibly wrong. It seems like it should be  scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(buttonWidth * x, buttonHeight  + padding);

Comment: i totally forgot about collectionview ....cheee

Comment: Add your scrollView first,after that add all button on scollView.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kindly check this code:

```
  UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 100)];

  int x = 0;
  CGRect frame;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    if (i == 0) {
      frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 80, 80);
    } else {
      frame = CGRectMake((i * 80) + (i*20) + 10, 10, 80, 80);
    }

    button.frame = frame;
    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTag:i];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickofFilter:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [scrollView addSubview:button];

    if (i == 9) {
      x = CGRectGetMaxX(button.frame);
    }

  }

  scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x, scrollView.frame.size.height);
  scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Comment: sure i will check and get back to you

Comment: have you tried it? you may replace x = CGRectGetMaxX(button.frame); with x = CGRectGetMaxX(button.frame) + 10; to add extra space at the end of the scrollView

Comment: nice answer Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4.2:

```
func addHorizontalTeamList() {

    let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 60))
    var frame : CGRect?

    for i in 0..<teamsCategory.count {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        if i == 0 {
            frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 130, height: 40)
        }else{
            frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(i * 140), y: 10, width: 130, height: 40)
        }

        button.frame = frame!
        button.tag = i
        button.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        button.rounded(border: 0, radius: button.frame.height/2)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectTeam), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.setTitle(teamsCategory[i].name, for: .normal)
        scrollView.addSubview(button)
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize( width: 840, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .white
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
}

@objc func selectTeam() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a similar code in swift 2.2 version for reference.**

```
    let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y,self.view.frame.width,35))
    var x = 0
    var frame : CGRect?



    for i in 0..<7 {

     let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)

        if i == 0 {

            frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 80, 20)

        }else{

            frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(i * 120), 5, 80, 20)


        }


        button.frame = frame!
        button.tag = i
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ProgramacioViewController.changeContentOnButtonSelection(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        scrollView.addSubview(button)


    }


    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake( 840, scrollView.frame.size.height)
    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 100)];

    int x = 0;

    NSUInteger value= [userInfo count];
    for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        [button setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato-Medium" size:12]];
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        button.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTag:i];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        button.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickSwipeButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.frame = CGRectMake((i * 100) + (i*10) + 10, 0, 100, 35);
        button.tag = i;
        x = CGRectGetMaxX(button.frame);
        [scrollView addSubview:button];

    }
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.randomView addSubview:scrollView];
```