# UIbutton method not getting called when added to view, scrollview & tablecell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

I am doing following steps and having problem with UIButton not getting called.

1) I create UIbutton objects array using for loop. called addTarget for all buttons and set tags also.

2) Used above array, placed all buttons to look like table columns in a view.

3) Add the above view in scroll view.

```
   set scrollview content size = view size
```

4) Now add above scrollview to cell.contentView as subview.

The issues I'm facing are :-

1) The scroll view not getting scrolled horizontally.

2) The button is not calling its methods

Answer (score 0):

Your Using Tableview and Scrolle view , Both are no need , If using Tableview why scroll view
If your using only scroll view follow below url

[Horizontal scroll with buttons in ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416995/horizontal-scroll-with-buttons-in-ios#comment41481207_26416995)

Answer (score 0):

If you want scroll view to scroll in table view cell you have to provide delegates to both table view and scroll view and make them implement:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
 return YES; }
```

Do not forget that content size of the scroll view must be bigger than it's frame size in order to scroll. Also, try setting contentView.userInteractionEnabled = NO; for button to become click-able.